# juju bootstrap in maas fails to retrieve juju tools

Tags: juju, maas

I installed MAAS, added the Nodes and created the juju but while i tried the following code

```
juju bootstrap
```

I am getting this error.

```
WARNING no tools available, attempting to retrieve from https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/
ERROR gomaasapi: got error back from server: 404 Not Found
```

How can i fix this ?

juju version 1.16.6-precise-i386
os version ubuntu-12.04.4-server-i386

this is the error i am facing

*

```
juju bootstrap --debug
2014-04-17 05:41:31 DEBUG juju.environs open.go:75 ConfigForName found bootstrap config map[string]interface {}{"default-series":"precise", "image-metadata-url":"", "tools-url":"", "admin-secret":"416286bfc6e9143566dc37749676ef18", "api-port":17070, "ca-private-key":"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\niPo5aYPszOwG7rt0TMD5qc4eclpm7dCEStU+H/LOW2Y=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "firewall-mode":"instance", "logging-config":"<root>=DEBUG", "maas-agent-name":"2ddaa65c-8f70-4845-8245-656d1f56e4c0", "maas-oauth":"KDPcnu7Sae4HT3SXm8:3Q3wTAhAgR6Rxyp3Tf:DBV45z3vFgjcj4wsv9dmL2t7sxMN9pEr", "type":"maas", "ca-cert":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nGgtap5rTxID3OuXZoVR1JqUKmg9jaAkMHQg+\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n", "development":false, "name":"maas", "state-port":37017, "authorized-keys":"ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDRAjETkuE1+AvuklQtzw/xQr0OjPjRDQuypqiwROZaar1Q5lrwxa/sUliZH+RiTqpvjiacoRgXHAXBWj/vXM+gaHVMlzi9i7j4Hs38hLbjcnEdLmA+pNqNWDuLhKfcd4PS26lrR8foHILqKbW8kWzHYGJnilJTH5zPn88ZIxTQgs1yFMzE1Uhb1uusP/nAOcGE1BbdvRsnO2ao1isos9+dFi7xz0ctVDBE0g+ZjNbTgKYfJDswpsS8frO1jwDvZqdPBzSaREc/j32KeRX+licYvesUz4d0kc5qTXalRNChUFhlAmB95tQJJQxeIpBj/5KSF3tnak+9g0uY7rRHmb13 root@motpl\n", "maas-server":"http://192.168.1.29:80/MAAS/", "ssl-hostname-verification":true}
2014-04-17 05:41:32 DEBUG juju.environs.configstore disk.go:77 Making /root/.juju/environments
2014-04-17 05:41:32 INFO juju.environs open.go:156 environment info already exists; using New not Prepare
2014-04-17 05:41:32 DEBUG juju.provider.maas environprovider.go:33 opening environment "maas".
2014-04-17 05:41:33 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju bootstrap.go:191 looking for bootstrap tools
2014-04-17 05:41:33 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:181 filtering tools by released version
2014-04-17 05:41:33 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:85 reading tools with major.minor version 1.16
2014-04-17 05:41:33 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:96 filtering tools by series: precise
2014-04-17 05:41:33 DEBUG juju.environs.tools tools.go:44 no architecture specified when finding tools, looking for any
2014-04-17 05:41:33 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:458 fetchData failed for "tools/streams/v1/index.sjson": file '2ddaa65c-8f70-4845-8245-656d1f56e4c0-tools/streams/v1/index.sjson' not found not found
2014-04-17 05:41:33 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:432 cannot load index "streams/v1/index.sjson": invalid URL "tools/streams/v1/index.sjson" not found
2014-04-17 05:41:33 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:458 fetchData failed for "tools/streams/v1/index.json": file '2ddaa65c-8f70-4845-8245-656d1f56e4c0-tools/streams/v1/index.json' not found not found
2014-04-17 05:41:33 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:432 cannot load index "streams/v1/index.json": invalid URL "tools/streams/v1/index.json" not found
2014-04-17 05:41:33 WARNING juju.cmd.juju bootstrap.go:204 no tools available, attempting to retrieve from https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/
2014-04-17 05:41:33 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:66 listing available tools
listing available tools
2014-04-17 05:41:33 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:33 reading v1.16 tools
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.0-precise-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.0-precise-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.0-quantal-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.0-quantal-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.0-raring-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.0-raring-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.0-saucy-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.0-saucy-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.2-precise-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.2-precise-armhf
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.2-precise-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.2-quantal-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.2-quantal-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.2-raring-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.2-raring-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.2-saucy-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.2-saucy-armhf
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.2-saucy-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.2-trusty-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.2-trusty-armhf
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.2-trusty-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.3-precise-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.3-precise-armhf
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.3-precise-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.3-quantal-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.3-quantal-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.3-raring-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.3-raring-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.3-saucy-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.3-saucy-armhf
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.3-saucy-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.3-trusty-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.3-trusty-armhf
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.3-trusty-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.4-precise-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.4-precise-armhf
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.4-precise-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.4-quantal-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.4-quantal-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.4-raring-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.4-raring-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.4-saucy-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.4-saucy-armhf
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.4-saucy-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.4-trusty-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.4-trusty-armhf
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.4-trusty-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.5-precise-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.5-precise-armhf
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.5-precise-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.5-quantal-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.5-quantal-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.5-raring-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.5-raring-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.5-saucy-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.5-saucy-armhf
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.5-saucy-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.5-trusty-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.5-trusty-armhf
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.5-trusty-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.6-precise-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.6-precise-armhf
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.6-precise-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.6-quantal-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.6-quantal-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.6-saucy-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.6-saucy-armhf
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.6-saucy-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.6-trusty-amd64
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.6-trusty-armhf
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.16.6-trusty-i386
2014-04-17 05:41:37 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:90 found 71 tools
found 71 tools
2014-04-17 05:41:37 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:94 found 11 recent tools (version 1.16.6)
found 11 recent tools (version 1.16.6)
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.sync sync.go:97 found source tool: &{1.16.6-precise-amd64 https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/tools/releases/juju-1.16.6-precise-amd64.tgz  0}
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.sync sync.go:97 found source tool: &{1.16.6-precise-armhf https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/tools/releases/juju-1.16.6-precise-armhf.tgz  0}
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.sync sync.go:97 found source tool: &{1.16.6-precise-i386 https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/tools/releases/juju-1.16.6-precise-i386.tgz  0}
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.sync sync.go:97 found source tool: &{1.16.6-quantal-amd64 https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/tools/releases/juju-1.16.6-quantal-amd64.tgz  0}
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.sync sync.go:97 found source tool: &{1.16.6-quantal-i386 https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/tools/releases/juju-1.16.6-quantal-i386.tgz  0}
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.sync sync.go:97 found source tool: &{1.16.6-saucy-amd64 https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/tools/releases/juju-1.16.6-saucy-amd64.tgz  0}
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.sync sync.go:97 found source tool: &{1.16.6-saucy-armhf https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/tools/releases/juju-1.16.6-saucy-armhf.tgz  0}
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.sync sync.go:97 found source tool: &{1.16.6-saucy-i386 https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/tools/releases/juju-1.16.6-saucy-i386.tgz  0}
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.sync sync.go:97 found source tool: &{1.16.6-trusty-amd64 https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/tools/releases/juju-1.16.6-trusty-amd64.tgz  0}
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.sync sync.go:97 found source tool: &{1.16.6-trusty-armhf https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/tools/releases/juju-1.16.6-trusty-armhf.tgz  0}
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.sync sync.go:97 found source tool: &{1.16.6-trusty-i386 https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/tools/releases/juju-1.16.6-trusty-i386.tgz  0}
2014-04-17 05:41:37 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:100 listing target bucket
listing target bucket
2014-04-17 05:41:37 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:35 reading v1.* tools
2014-04-17 05:41:37 ERROR juju supercommand.go:282 gomaasapi: got error back from server: 404 Not Found
```

*

After updating juju i am getting the following error

juju bootstrap
WARNING failed to write bootstrap-verify file: gomaasapi: got error back from server: 404 Not Found (



Object not found!

*/-->

## Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server.



    If you entered the URL manually please check your
    spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact
the webmaster.

### Error 404

192.168.1.29
  Apache/2.4.4 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

)
Bootstrap failed, destroying environment
ERROR Bootstrap failed, and the environment could not be destroyed: gomaasapi: got error back from server: 404 Not Found (



Object not found!

*/-->

## Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server.



    If you entered the URL manually please check your
    spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact
the webmaster.

### Error 404

192.168.1.29
  Apache/2.4.4 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

)
ERROR provider storage is not writable

Comment: Can you add the juju version, OS, OS version to your question.

Answer (score 3):

So starting at zero, can this server reach https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/ e.g.

```
# it's ok if you don't have xmllint installed
curl -X GET https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/ | xmllint --format -
```

[image]

Comment: Still, I am facing the same error.

Comment: Please update your post with the content of "juju bootstrap --debug". Find and remove all instances of access-key and secret-key before posting. Does juju work at all for you on any cloud?

Comment: i updated my question please check it.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bug. Please post what you've found to https://launchpad.net/juju-core and then upgrade to 1.18 by visting https://juju.ubuntu.com/install/ and follow the install instructions.

Comment: i updated my question please check it.